# How to run test using VS on iOS simulator(on mac)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

Just started investigate the Xamarin Test Cloud.
I want to write a simple test using VS and run this test on iOS simulator, which is running on Mac machine.
I've connected to Xamarin Mac Agent. Agent run on the same Mac machine as the iOS simulator.

I've faced with exception "iOS tests are not supported on Windows" when i'm trying to use something like this:

```
app = ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
```

I'm understand that I can't run iOS tests on Windows, but I want to run it on iOS simulator on Mac.

Could someone explain me how can I do this? Is it possible?

And a have another question. As a said I've just started with the xamarin and tests. I'm not shure that I undertand difference between Xamarin Test Cloud and Xamarin UI Test. Could someone explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible at this time to launch iOS tests on the simulator (running on your Mac) from Visual Studio - you'd have to start the tests from Xamarin Studio on the Mac itself to be able to run the tests in the simulator or on a device.

UITest is the Automated UI Acceptance Testing *framework* based on Calabash that allows programmers to write and execute tests in C# - [more info can be found at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/).

Test Cloud is a *service* that allows you to run tests written with UITest (or Calabash) on over 2,000 devices that we host ourselves (so you can test against various different OS versions / types of hardware). - [more info can be found at this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: hello! we can't do it until now?