# regarding Remote Simulator to Windows

Tags: xamarin, ios-simulator

When I run my Xamarin iOS test via Visual Studio 2017, I got the following message: “iOS tests are not supported on Windows”. I have set up Remote Simulator to Windows option so it should open simulator but it didn't happen so please tell me what's wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator/index

Here is my test configuration:
I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Version 15.8.5 with Xamarin version 4.11.
I have created new Test Project using Xamarin.UITest Cross-Platform Test Project template.
I have also configured Mac Book using Pair to Mac option and it is connected fine.
I have checked Remote Simulator to Windows option in IOS Settings via VS Tools options in order to run my test on remote simulator.
I have following code in my Test.cs file

```
if (platform == Platform.iOS)
{
return ConfigureApp
.iOS
.InstalledApp("com.example.yourappbundleid")
.EnableLocalScreenshots()
.StartApp();                   
}
```

When I run the test, I got the following message: iOS tests are not supported on Windows.
As I have said earlier, I have set up Remote Simulator to Windows option so it should open simulator but it didn't happen so please tell me what's wrong? 
I knew we can't run test directly on windows machine using actual device but I should open the remote simulator.
Please suggest me the solution or any updated information you have regarding running iOS test on Remote Simulator.
Many thanks in advance.
SPatel

Comment: You would have to run those tests directly from the Mac itself as the UITest driver is using Apple's XCUITest to drive the UI automation and that is not compatible with the way that Xamarin's iOS remoting works (basically a UI "hack")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592837/how-to-run-test-using-vs-on-ios-simulatoron-mac

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Really appreciate your help.