# I would like to connect my Iphone to a MAC mini and remotely run tests on it from my Windows machine using Xamarin UI test

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I am getting the error saying **"iOS tests are not supported on Windows"** while trying to execute UI test script written against the Xamarin.UI.Test framework.

*Is there any way to remotely run UI test on IOS app from Visual studio 2017 (windows machine)?*

Appium has a remote server feature which enable us to connect to mac and run test script. Does Xamarin UI test has any feature like this?

Comment: Pair to Mac option ?

Comment: That is not working while running UI test from visual studio.  It is working when simply run the Ios application from VS2017.

Answer (score 3):

Running iOS Xamarin.UITests from Windows using the Mac Agent is not supported.

**Cause:**

> The UITest driver is using Apple's XCUITest to drive the UI automation
>   and that is not compatible with the way that Xamarin's iOS remoting
>   works (basically a UI "hack").

**Solution:**

You can instead run them directly on the Mac using Xamarin Studio.

Refer:[How to run test using VS on iOS simulator(on mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592837/how-to-run-test-using-vs-on-ios-simulatoron-mac)