# Visual Studio Pair to Mac only available in some solutions

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a Visual Studio project (on windows) with Xamarin UI Tests in it. I'd like to run them against a physical device connected to a Mac that I have access to. 
In my UI test solution, I don't have access to Pair to Mac. The icon is present in the menu, but clicking on it does nothing. 
However, if I open a new ios template solution, or an existing ios templated solution, I can pair and connect to my mac just fine.

Is there some setting I need to set on the solution to be able to use Pair to Mac? I'm on Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10 if it matters.

Comment: You will need to use the Mac directly for local UITests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-ios-simulator?tabs=vswin

Comment: So, what's the purpose of Pair to Mac then?
 I've seen a couple different tutorials referencing using the paired mac as a remote connection in the build config, but I can't figure out how to actually run the tests on the mac from my windows machine. 
(ex: https://www.jimbobbennett.io/ui-testing-your-xamarin-apps/)

Comment: `...what's the purpose of Pair to Mac then...` To compile/debug the iOS project... in that link, he is using Visual Studio for Mac to run the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do Xamarin.UITest

- For **Android** apps: you can use either Visual studio for Windows or Visual studio for Mac.
- For **iOS** apps: you have to use a Mac, it is not support on Windows so
  far.

Refer:

[i-would-like-to-connect-my-iphone-to-a-mac-mini-and-remotely-run-tests-on-it-fro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494275/i-would-like-to-connect-my-iphone-to-a-mac-mini-and-remotely-run-tests-on-it-fro/53511413#53511413)

[uitest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-ios-simulator?tabs=vswin)

There is also a feature request someone opened in Github and you can follow this to get the lasest information: [Run Xamarin.UITest for iOS locally on Windows via connected Mac's iOS simulator](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/574)